if I have the bandwidth and max bit rate of an environment, how can find the max possible QAM level?
Lets say B = 2MHz and the max bit rate is 27 Mbps. According to Nyquist's theorem: 27 = 4 * log2 (L) So L will be around 107.63 . Now which is the max QAM Level I can choose? 64-QAM or 128-QAM?

Is this rather an [electronics.se] or [ham.se] question, or are you referring to a topic you can ask about here, as laid out in our [help/on-topic]?
